A activiti6 workflow, which method is applicable to the production environment for querying to-do tasks?
Everyone who has used activiti workflow, is this the way to use it?
The review status is divided into draft, to be reviewed (manager ->supervisor ->Boss to review in turn) and approved.
The approval process is: draft ->manager to be approved ->supervisor to be approved ->boss to be approved ->approved.
How to use activiti6. Create a record. After the record is submitted, start the process, set the current user as the person who collects the task (through the claim method) and complete the task (through the complete method). Then it will automatically flow to the next approver. Before approval or rejection, you need to set the person who receives the record as yourself (through the claim method), and then approve it (through the complete method). Is this the approval process?
There is also a query process: query the list of records whose business data is in the To Do list, and then enter the approval stage and approval records before you need to query the data of related approval records in the table in activiti6, right? I think the official demo is to directly query the records of the task list. I don't understand its purpose, because it is impossible to define the query order and filter conditions according to some data in the business table.
enter image description here
However, this does not meet the following conditions: when querying, the status and submission time are in your own business data table, and the data related to the approval time are in the activiti6 table. If you want to query the records that are in the status of pending approval and are the records to be approved by the supervisor, you should also get them in reverse order according to the submission time of the business data records. Is there a better way to do this? If the table is not associated, can't it be implemented; But if business data and tables in activiti are not the same library.
How to obtain which user group is the next approval stage in the current process of approval?
